# Why are React JavaScript files reverting to JavaScript language mode after being changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I create a new React or React Native project and create a new file whose extension is JS its language mode is being JavaScript. I'm manually changing JavaScript to JavaScript React. When I change page or close and open a page it's changing to JavaScript again. What should I do?

```
{

    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

this is jsconfig.js file

Comment: Is there something wrong with using `jsx` extension?

Comment: no i just wanna use js extension

Comment: When you say JavaScript React, do you mean a JSX file?